# Web server down in some places in the world for short time

Tags: windows-server-2008, web-server, iis-7, networking

Hello I have a Windows Server 2008 VPS, located in USA with a Web Site (IIS7) that publish contents to Mexico and Argentina. Sometimes I lose connectivity for short period of time (about 5 minutes), sometime happens accessing from Mexico, and sometimes accessing from Argentina, but never in the same time. Resulting in a 404 error.

I'm monitoring the web pages (HTTP and DNSs) using site24x7.com from USA and Brazil and it never felt down, I don't understand how it is possible.

Any Idea?

Thank you
Santiago

Comment: the network path site24x7.com takes to get to the site vs. the path you take may be different.

Comment: Start with the Log files (server and IIS) and go from there.